# Не работает go get на приватных репозиториях bitbucket ! ошибка 403

Tags: golang, модули

Проблема следующая. У меня не работает go-mod . На закрытые  bitbucket репы всегда ошибка:
`go: bitbucket.org/wimarksystems/liblog@v1.4.0: reading https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/wimarksystems/liblog?fields=scm: 403 Forbidden
 server response: Access denied. You must have write or admin access.`
Ключ я добавил, даже два. Один свой, другой специально для битбакета создавал. В  gitconfig закинул емаил и юзер найм от аккаунта. При этом, я могу сделать git pull или git push, и вижу что он использует ключ, но когд делаю go get такое ощущение что ключ просто не используется. Я даже версию го переустанавливал c 1.14.4 на 1.12.7.

Все ключи прописаны на bitbucket. Версия go 1.13.5. Так же пробовал на остальных.

Comment: GOPRIVATE тоже выставлял
Это тоже делал git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если судить по
[информации из *FAQ*](https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https),
то в вашем `~/.netrc` должно быть что-то типа:

```
machine api.bitbucket.org login YOUR_LOGIN password YOUR_PASSWORD_OR_API_KEY
```

Comment: а что делать если у меня нет .netrc

Comment: кст там же написано, что это для кофигурации через пароль, но меня же интересует ssh ключ